# CDP Reveal question

Tags: switch, vlan, cdp

1) does CDP reveal vlan ID, voice vlan ID, trunk native vlan ID??
Or only Vlan ID and voice vlan id?

2) Also what is native vlan and default vlan? Is there a simple explanation?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

CDP short for Cisco Discovery Porocol is a proprietary protocol developed by cisco to discover information about directly connected devices via the Data Link Layer.

It can not determine vlan alone.

Native VLAN is the vlan assigned to not be tagged.
Default VLAN from cisco is vlan 1

Comment: https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/switches/catalyst-4500-series-switches/13414-103.html#cdp Version 2 added vlan information (native, and voice [aka Appliance]) VTP is required to learn more than those basic VLANs.